# I have installed all the python libraries i want to use in the vscode terminal but when i call to import, it won't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

```
[{
    "resource": "/d:/Users/Home/Desktop/Python/estudos/pratices.py",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "reportMissingModuleSource",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#reportMissingModuleSource",
            "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "github.com",
            "fragment": "reportMissingModuleSource"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Import \"pandas\" could not be resolved from source",
    "source": "Pylance",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 8,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 14
}]
```

is the message given
the cmd shell tells me i have all the libraries i want installed and they're in the project folder, i'm running a virtual environment but whenever i try to run something in a .py file, it says that it's not defined, i have installed anaconda but don't mean to use it right now, if i open a jupyter file it'll import no problem, but trying to run pip doesn't work at all

reinstalling vscode, making sure python's installed, making sure pip is installed

Comment: what if you run the python script from the terminal `python pratices.py`, find out if your virt env is active and if you have installed the stuff in the virt env, use `pip` to list installed modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before and the solution I found is that you have to make sure the python interpreter for the current VSC window is your virtual environment instead of the system-wide python interpreter. On windows:

- Press F1
- Search for "interpreter".
- Click the python one
- Click "Enter interpreter path".
- Finally locate your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the current interpreter and the `pandas` library installed are the same interpreter environment.

The current interpreter can be output with the following code.

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Then install the `pandas` library with the resulting interpreter path.

```
<the path obtained above> -m pip install pandas
```

[image]